# Basic questions on the yield curve

Tags: yield-curve, bond-yields, yield

When people say "yield curve", do they mean yield/time curve, or yield/price curve?

It seems that most of the time, people refer to yield/time curve, as [wikipedia suggests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_curve). Though sometimes, people seem to use this term referring to yield/price curve, often when talking about the convexity, like here in [investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/negative_convexity.asp).

What is the right definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually yield/time is the standard context for definition of a yield curve, with yields being derived from prices (of interest rate instruments) for certain maturities (times). 
The investopedia article you are referencing is all about the yield/price connection (since duration  and convexity represent first and second order "price" sensitivity measures to "rate" changes) - so that is why you shouldn't view that article as the default context for yield curve lingo.